# Laravel artisan: listen command every second

Tags: laravel, cron, microservices, amqp

I have two microservices which communicate with help AMQP.

I use bschmitt/laravel-amqp https://github.com/bschmitt/laravel-amqp.

I created one action for publish message to queue.

Then I created artisan command which consume message from queue.
Example of publisher:

`Amqp::publish('', $user->toJson() , ['queue' => 'MS:USER:CREATED']);`

Example of consumer:

```
Amqp::consume('MS:USER:CREATED', function ($message, $resolver) {
                $result = json_decode($message->body);
                    Log::info($result);
                    $resolver->acknowledge($message);

                    $resolver->stopWhenProcessed();

            });
```

I need to listen this command every second. For this I use supervisor.

Example of supervisor configuration:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/user/Projects/other/user/artisan ms:user:created
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=user
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/user/Projects/other/user/worker.log
```

But supervisor start and after few second down.
This is output of error when I restart supervisor:

```
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_02: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_06: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_00: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_01: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_04: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_07: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_03: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_05: ERROR (spawn error)
```

Then in order to get the messages I need to restart the supervisor every time.

Also I know another approach:

Wrap Amqp::consume  and use crontab for this.

Example:

```
 while (true) {
            Amqp::consume('MS:USER:CREATED', function ($message, $resolver) {

//some part of code
});
   sleep(1);
        }
```

This approach work, but I don't think that this is good idea.

Maybe in approach with supervisor I have wrong configuration for this case.

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: https://github.com/bschmitt/laravel-amqp mentions that removing `stopWhenProcessed` will result in consuming messages forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using a while loop in Bash in the supervisor configuration command

```
[program:ms-user-created]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/bin/sh -c "while [ true ]; do (php /home/user/Projects/other/user/artisan ms:user:created &); sleep 1; done"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=2
user=www-data
redirect_stderr=true
```